# How to import this xml feed into sql with auto update?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a little problem and i cant find any results on internet.

My boss have a xml feed from his products provider and he asked me to insert all data from xml link into mysql website db.

So i begin like this:

```
#database
$sql= new MySQL();
//connect to db   
$host = 'localhost';   
$user = 'user';   
$pass = 'pass';   
$db = 'dbname';     

$sql = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $pass) or die("Error - Unable to Connect");     

mysql_select_db($db) or die("Error- Unable to find database");                     

// specify url of xml file   

$url = "thehttpofurlproducts";         

// get xml file contents   

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);   

foreach ($xml->Items->Item as $item) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO products (id,code,info) VALUES ($item->prod_id, $item->prod_code,$item->prod_info)";
    $result = mysql_unbuffered_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());
}  
mysql_close($connection);
```

And there are many others fields he wanted me to import into sql db. 
He want to make this run in real time so i use cronjobs. But the problem is how to update the products in realtime . When i run this second time it gives me errors like duplicate key, etc.

The xml is like this and its continously update :

```
<Message>
<EntityType>Products</EntityType>
<Items>
<Item>
<prod_id>235</prod_id>
<prod_code>xzq</prod_code>
<prod_name>Dogs</prod_name>
<prod_info><prod_info/>
<isstoc>false</isstoc>
<UM>UM</UM>
<VAT>20.00</VAT>
<prod_category>Puppies</prod_category>
<prod_subcategory>--</prod_subcategory>
<Onlineprice>0.00</Onlineprice>
<Stock>0.00</Stock>
<Weight/>
</Item>
</Items>
</MESSAGE>
```

Comment: please remove the sql-server tag if this is mysql only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). It'll allow you to update values instead of inserting a new row with the same value.

In your example you could do

```
...
$query = "INSERT INTO products (id,code,info) VALUES ($item->prod_id, $item->prod_code,$item->prod_info) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code = $item->prod_code, info = $item->prod_info";
...
```

I'd also advice you to sanitize your query's parameters before appending them to your query for safety reasons.

Comment: i;ve got error : Error in query: INSERT INTO products (id,code,info) VALUES ('44', 'zxf', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code = 44, . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 .  can u help me improve the script? i will p@y you

Comment: @vuuduuz There appears to be a comma at the end of your query statement. Could that be causing the error?

Comment: @vuuduuz Are you still getting the same error or something else? Using the query `INSERT INTO products (id,code,info) VALUES ('44', 'zxf', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code = 44` doesn't give syntax errors for me.

Comment: ehe, thank . works now. What u want to say in previous comment : " I'd also advice you to sanitize your query's parameters before appending them to your query for safety reasons." ? Isn;t this a good method to make a conexion from xml to sql in opencart or?

Comment: @vuuduuz What I mean is that with the way you pass your variables into the query it's prone to SQL injection. Unless you're 100% sure the XML files are from a trusted source (user input is not to be trusted) search the web for preventing SQL injection.